# didEnterRegion and didExitRegion not being called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-location, geofencing

I am developing an app through xCode which uses geofencing and region monitoring. Through monitoring these regions upon enter and exit, a pop up is meant to be called to display to the user the location they are now in (or exiting) said location. When I use my .gpx file to simulate leaving and entering the location or entering/leaving the location myself, unfortunately the enter and exit functions never get called.

Before recent updates in Xcode my code worked perfectly and enter and exit functions were being called. They do not call now and have not been for quite some time. I've done a lot of research on the matter and have found with updates in Xcode, changing `manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` to       `manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` and updating plist files accordingly should resolve this error (`manager = CLLocationManager`). I've tried this and have updated my code but to no avail.

Below is a picture of my P-List Files for user location requests.

[image: P-List Request Files]

I've placed my code pertaining to this problem below and I and others would greatly appreciate any help or ideas on how to fix this problem as it does seem to be re-occuring in the updated xCode. Thank you:)

P.S. The other locationManager functions are being called. Which include the didUpdateLocations and the didStartMonitoring.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate,        CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    mapView.delegate = self
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.follow, animated: true)

    let title = "Oakville Test"
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.477521, -79.712430)
    let regionRadius = 150.0

    // setup region
    let region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude), radius: regionRadius, identifier: title)
    region.notifyOnEntry = true
    region.notifyOnExit = true
    locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    // setup annotation
    let annotationView = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotationView.coordinate = coordinate;
    annotationView.title = "\(title)";
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotationView)

    // setup circle
    let circle = MKCircle(center: coordinate, radius: regionRadius)
    mapView.add(circle)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    if overlay is MKPolyline {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
        renderer.lineWidth = 5.0
        renderer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        return renderer
    } else {
        let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        circleRenderer.lineWidth = 1.0
        circleRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        return circleRenderer
    }
    return nil
}

func showAlert(_ title: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: nil)
    let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(yesAction)
    alert.addAction(noAction)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLRegion) {
    print("The monitored regions are: \(manager.monitoredRegions)")
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    showAlert("You are at \(region.identifier)!")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    showAlert("leaving \(region.identifier).")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are all of locationManager functions not being called? Or just didEnter/didExitRegion?

Comment: Yes, the other locationManager functions are being called. Being the didStartMonitoringFor region and the didUpdateLocations.

Comment: Im not sure if this will work but try casting your CLCircularRegion to a CLRegion as the didEnterRegion function takes a type of CLRegion

Comment: Just implemented that, unfortunately it didn't work. Thank you for the idea though!

Comment: Hey everyone! I've actually resolved the problem. The problem wasn't in the code but rather my .gpx file. So for anyone here with a similar problem check your gpx and also the above code is functional and usable!

Comment: Cool good work, I will be doing something similar so might borrow some of you code :)

Comment: Hi @LucasO, I'm facing the same issue. I'm changing location from simulator "Feature" tab but didEnterRegion is not being called. This is strange because it is only not working in iOS 12 whereas when I run the same code in iOS 13 then it works fine.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, that was my issue too. @Rajat Mishra, I had the same issue from the Feature tab, I can only get these events working from Xcode's "Simulate Location" button (which doesn't always appear for some reason)